# Selecting features in attribute table using maximum aggregate function

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, expression

I have a table containing distances from one ID (an address) to another ID (bus stops).

There table contains distances from all addresses to all different bus stops.

Now I want to select the feature where the distance between the certain address and the bus stop is the shortest.

In QGIS I've tried to do something like this:

[image]

where:

- `"meter"` is the distance column;
- `"fromID"` is the address.

There are 16 different addresses and a little more than 6000 features in the table. What I need is a table with only 16 features.

You can, of course, use minimum function as well.

Can anybody help out here?

Comment: What happens when removing the white space between `:` and `=` in the `group_by` statement?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Actually it removed the syntax error, but unfortunately all the 6,000+ features are selected.
Can you guide me a step further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following expression in the **Select by Expression** tool:

```
"meter" = maximum( "meter", "fromID" )
```

This selects all `"meter"` values which equals the maximum `"meter"` value found for each `"fromID"` group.

Comment: @HowToInQGIS - Thanks, I tested it on a _much_ smaller attribute table so will be interesting to see if it works for the OP ;)

Comment: Just tested on 6000 features and it works! However, @kwiwe I suggest you to deactivate the layer from the Layers Panel when editing the fields because QGIS may crash when managing/rendering too many features.

Comment: @HowToInQGIS - Nice one, thanks for testing! Also, good advice =)

Comment: The solution worked for me as well :-).
Thank you so much for your help.
But can I conclude, though, that you cannot do this operation i `select by expression`only?

Comment: @kwiwe - Edited my post, you can indeed use the `select by expression`. You just need to provide it with a filter :)

Comment: @Joseph - What filter should I use?

Comment: @kwiwe - See my edited post, you need to make the `meter` field equal to your expression.

Comment: Jup. It does the thing.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @kwiwe - Most welcome, glad it helped ;)

Comment: @kwiwe Please, remember to accept the answer if it helped you to find the solution.

Comment: @HowToInQGIS - Done! I was not aware of that. Quite new here :-).

Comment: No problem. If you like this place, you could take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works. =)