# Select highest value in multiple polygons

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon shapefile and a point shapefile. The point shapefile has the following attributes: X, Y,height (derivated from a reaster DEM) and the polygon unique ID.

I want to select the highest point on each polygon, but I don't know how to use the correct expression to accomplish it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting features in attribute table using maximum aggregate function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224907/selecting-features-in-attribute-table-using-maximum-aggregate-function)

Comment: The question is not duplicate because here there is two shapefile. So first you need to create a join between shape to get  only one table. Then process as its show on this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224907/selecting-features-in-attribute-table-using-maximum-aggregate-function

Comment: If the point layer already contains the polygon ID, what is the polygon layer needed for?

Answer (score 1):

Using the select by expression tool:

```
HEIGHT= maximum( "HEIGHT" , "POLYGONID" )
```

[Selecting features in attribute table using maximum aggregate function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224907/selecting-features-in-attribute-table-using-maximum-aggregate-function)